# 2 different sorts, 1 functor

Tags: c++, sorting, stl, functor

I have a functor that I am using to compare 2 values, and if those 2 values are equal it then relies on sorting by alphabetical.

Here is an example functor for a class called `test` who has attributes accessors `GetValue` and `GetName`

```
struct test_comp {
    bool operator() (const test* a, const test* b) const {
        if(a->GetValue() == b->GetValue()) {
            return a->GetName() < b->GetName();
        } else {
            return a->GetValue() > b->GetValue();
        }

    }
};
```

This effectively will sort an STL container by largest `value` and if then within each value by alphabetical `name`

Then I am trying to output 2 things:

The first N elements of the STL container and the last N elements of the STL, both sorted alphabetically if the value is equal.

Here is my code, using an STL list `test_list`:

```
test_list.sort(test_comp);

cout << "First 5:" << endl;
n = 1;
for (auto it = test_list.begin(); it != test_list.end(); ++it) {
    cout << (*it)->GetName() << " " << (*it)->GetValue() << endl;
    if(++n > 5) {
        break;
    }
}

cout << "Last 5:" << endl;
m = 5;
for (auto it = test_list.rbegin(); it != test_list.rend(); ++it) {
    cout << (*it)->GetName() << " " << (*it)->GetValue() << endl;
    if(--m < 1) {
        break;
    }
}
```

For example Consider this list:

```
name  value
A     1
B     4
C     1
A     3
B     3
C     3
A     4
B     1
C     4
```

### Correct Output:

First 5 :

```
name  value
A     4
B     4
C     4
A     3
B     3
```

Last 5:

```
name  value
A     1
B     1
C     1
A     3
B     3
```

### My Output:

First 5 :

```
name  value
A     4
B     4
C     4
A     3
B     3
```

Last 5 :

```
name  value
C     1
B     1
A     1
C     3
B     3
```

As you can see in "Last 5" the alphabetical sorting is maintained and when iteratoring reversely the alphabetical is decending now, when I still want it to be ascending. The only way I know how to do what I want is by using 2 functors and 2 sorts. I am curious if there is a way to do it using 1 functor and 1 sort.

Edit 1:

Fixed some typos of a comparing to a.

Edit 2:

More clear about output differences

Comment: You're iterating through the last 5 elements in reverse order. So why would you expect to see them in alphabetical order? It's reverse alphabetical, just as one would expect.

Comment: Yes, The code works as expected. I am more wondering how someone may solve it the way I want it without using 2 almost identical functors and 2 sorts.

Comment: When I test your code, I get _very_ different results than you're reporting: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b7d2007d48a18208

Comment: Sorry I had some similar a's and b's http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d405e241a729dd78

Comment: @BHare: Well, it looks like that solved the problem, right?

Comment: @MooingDuck the issue is getting the Last 5 in ascending alphabetical and not decending

Comment: @BHare: Well, you've posted two sets of "Last 5" in the question that are both wrong.  Which one is your code producing?  The link _you just posted_ in the comments appears 100% correct to me

Comment: Made outputs more clear in edit.

Comment: Are you stuck with using `std::list`? Do you have the option of switching to a more useful container, such as `std::vector`?

Comment: @BHare: Well, now your "Correct Output" looks insane and makes no sense to me, and your "My Output" appears correct, merely in reverse.  Because, you know, you printed it in reverse.  The problem is _you're printing the last 5 in reverse_.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain but this looks very very wrong

```
bool operator() (const test* a, const test* b) const {
    if(a->GetValue() == a->GetValue()) { //comparing a to a?
        return a->GetName() < b->GetName();
    } else {
        return a->GetValue() > a->GetValue(); //comparing a to a?
    }

}
```

Maybe if you compare `a` to `b` you'll get better results.

After your edit, now your "Correct Output" looks insane and makes no sense to me, and your "My Output" appears correct, merely in reverse. Because, you know, you printed it in reverse. The problem is you're printing the last 5 in reverse.

Comment: Sorry I was making the accessors more generic for SO and forgot to change copied code. Fixed